# Выборка текста из html

Tags: c#, .net, html, синтаксический-анализ

Необходимо выбрать текст из html кода.
Например, дано:

```
<div>first</div><div>second</div><br /><div> third</div>.
```

Нужно получить:

> first second third

Пробовал использовать `jQuery.text()`, но получаю:

> firstsecond third

Что есть не очень хорошо.

Так как это сделать средствами `.NET`, используя, быть может, сторонние библиотеки? И желательно как можно более производительно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот сторонние библиотеки

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

[Html Agility Pack — удобный .NET парсер HTML](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112325/)

Answer (score 3):

Если вы уж использовали jQuery.text()  то почему хотите использовать .NET сейчас, а не переписать код на правильный?
Пример:

```
var txt = [] // массив в котором весь текст
//собираем текст
$('div').each(function(){
  txt.push( $(this).text()) //заполняем массив
})
//или так
$('div').text(function(index,text){
  txt.push( text )
})
console.log ( txt.join(' ') ) //делаем с ним все что вздумается
```

UPD. Ответ был дан с привязкой к вопросу. $('div') - можно заменить на любую интересующую конструкцию:

$('*') возьмет все элементы страницы.

$('#id *') - возьмет все элементы внутри блока с id='id'

Я думаю эту часть подкорректировать не составит труда под конкретные нужды :)

Comment: а что если текст будет:
<h4>first</h4>second? Я имел ввиду ЛЮБОЙ код HTML

Comment: замените $('div') на нужную конструкцию :)

Comment: в общем случае не известно содержание html, метод должен быть универсален